# Username and password via Nuget.Config are not working for file share

Tags: nuget

I have a VS2017 solution with a private nuget repository. As a repository, I'm using a simple file share (protected via username/password). I've placed the NuGet.Config file in solution root (so that not every developer has to add the private repository manually).

I've added my private repository via the following command:

```
nuget.exe sources Add -Name mySource -UserName user -Password secret -Configfile C:\MySolutionDirectory\NuGet.Config
```

When opening the NuGet.Config file I see a `<packageSourceCredentials>` element (as described [on msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)) with the correct username and the password in encrypted form.

When I perform a fresh checkout and build the solution via VS 2017 the nuget package manager can't connect to the given file share. If I open the file share in the Windows Explorer and enter the credentials manually, building the solution via VS2017 works.

Does anyone know if nuget supports authentication for a file share?